# What big families of theories/structures are there?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, universal-algebra, big-picture

To gain a big picture of (pre-categorical) mathematics, is it correct to divide mathematical theories resp. structures in two big families?

- universal algebra: classes of objects with arbitrary functions and relations/properties defined on them (basically first order)
- universal topology: classes of objects with arbitrary functions and relations/properties defined on *sets* of those objects (basically second order)

The distinction is not as sharp as it seems, because there is e.g. [pointless topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointless_topology), and because every theory/structure can be defined in set theory, which is first order.

> What is missing in this "big picture"? Are there (pre-categorical)
>   theories/structures that fall in none of these two families?

(I emphasize "pre-categorical" because for example "algebraic topology" is a genuine theory but seems to be about something completely different than "classes of objects with functions and relations defined on both themselves **and** sets of them".)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to place under the umbrella of 'pre-categorical' mathematics. Algebraic topology for instance doesn't **have** to be formulated using the language of category theory, and indeed some choose to teach the subject without referring to categories at all (possibly to the students' detriment). Similarly, it's possible to talk about groups entirely using category theory and forgoing sets (every group is a category with one objects with all morphisms invertible). Could you perhaps try to make your distinction more precise?

Comment: "Pre-categorical" is supposed to mean: trying to "attack" structures the direct way: as structured sets. But - I have to admit - this makes my question somehow vacuous. So I guess, it is hard to make precise my distinction - and maybe, I am just begging for help to make this distinction more precise? (no cheating or irony)

Comment: I think at the root of it your question is an interesting one (maybe one which can be made more precise by a logician) but one which is hard to answer without being made more precise. Maybe someone with a better logical background can give some input.